# How do I check if ReSharper.ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode has finished?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to run ReSharper's `ReSharper.ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode` before a file is saved (using a `RunningDocumentTable`).

The problem I'm having is that `DTE.ExecuteCommand( "ReSharper.ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode" );` is a "fire and forget" command, and I have no way of knowing when it has finished. This is a problem if the command takes longer to return then expected and the file gets saved BEFORE ReSharper has applied the changes.

Is there a way to monitor this command, and respond when it has finished?